# How to update my branch when I already made some changes

Tags: git, bitbucket

I created a branch from master before updating it. I made some changes on the branch and I committed and then pushed the branch. After pushing I realized the branch I was working on was not created from updated master branch. My question now is, how possibly can I move those changes to a branch I create from updated master branch.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff in git. Did you read the docs: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to solve this would be to merge an updated master into your branch.

Let's take the steps.

You had this:

```
             master
               v
*----*----*----*
```

Then you did this:

```
             master
               v
*----*----*----*
                \
                 *---*---*
                         ^
                       branch
```

In reality you had this:

```
             master   origin/master
               v           v
*----*----*----*---*---*---*
                \
                 *---*---*
                         ^
                       branch
```

The simplest way would be to update master, then merge it into your branch, using these commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout branch
git merge master
```

This would give you this:

```
                         master
                      origin/master
                           v
*----*----*----*---*---*---*
                \           \
                 *---*---*---*
                             ^
                           branch
```

If you instead really need your branch to be based on the updated master, then instead of merging master into your branch you have to rebase your branch on top of master, using these commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull                      ;; the first two are the same as above, to update
git checkout branch
git rebase master
```

These commands would give you this result:

```
                         master
                      origin/master
                           v
*----*----*----*---*---*---*
                            \
                             *---*---*
                                     ^
                                   branch
```

Comment: Super helpful, tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Pull from master Branch and follow step 2.

Step 2. first, you create a new branch.

```
git branch <BranchName>
git checkout <BranchName>
git add -a -m "commt name"
git push
```

and then create pull request from  to Master.

Done

Comment: I dont get it. When do I add my changes to the new branch. My changes are on the old branch I have already committed.

Comment: can you edit your question and write your exact question? it's difficult to understand. thanks

Answer (score 0):

By your question i got , that the branch you have created and pushed is behind master branch and that changes you want to pull in in to the branch that you have created and pushed ? Right if yes then

```
git checkout master
git pull
git log
```

**#Take the latest commit id from log and rebase it to the branch that you have created and pushed**

```
git checkout <branch>
git rebase <Commit-id>
git push
```

Please let me know if it worked or i understood your question properly or not.